# C#で配列から特定の要素が含まれる数を取得したい

Tags: c#

C#で、ある配列から複数の要素が連続して含まれる数を出力するようにしたいです。例えば、

string型の {“A”,”B”,”F”,”D”,”A”,”B”,”A”,”G”}

という配列があったときに、
　　「”A”,”B”の組み合わせは配列内に2個存在している」
　　　(AとBを個別の要素としてではなく、連続した2つの要素として検索する)

と出力するようにしたいです。
上の例でいくと「A、またはBが含まれる数をカウントする」というのは調べたら出てきましたが、「連続した要素として探す」というのは出てこなかったです(調べ方が悪いと思いますが...。)
初歩的な質問をしてしまっていると思いますが
よろしくお願いします！

Comment: ちなみに char ではなく string ということは、各要素が1文字だけではない可能性もあるということでしょうか？

Comment: そうです！　分かりにくくてすみません

Answer (score 2, accepted):

地道に数えるしかありません。例えばこんな感じ。

```
string[] strs = ["A", "B", "F", "D", "A", "B", "A", "G"];
var count = strs.Take(strs.Length - 1).Where((cur, i) => cur == "A" && strs[i + 1] == "B").Count();
Console.WriteLine($"""”A”,”B”の組み合わせは配列内に{count}個存在している""");
```

- ある要素が`A`でその隣の要素が`B`という条件を満たす個数を数える。
- 「隣の要素」にアクセスするために、[`Where()`拡張メソッドのインデックス付きバージョン](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-system-boolean))))を使用する。

  - インデックス付きの拡張メソッドは`Select()`と`Where()`くらいにしか用意されておらず、もちろん、条件付きカウントを実現する`Count()`拡張メソッドにも存在しない。
- 配列の境界を越えてしまわないように、`Take()`拡張メソッドで要素数を制限する。

無理にLINQを使わなくても`for`ループを書いてもいいですし、そっちの方が効率もいいです。

---

payanecoさんの回答で[`Zip()`拡張メソッド](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=net-8.0)が使えることを失念していました。特に.NET Core 3.0以降で`ValueTuple`を返すオーバーロードが追加されていますので、シンプルに書けました。

```
var count = strs.Zip(strs.Skip(1)).Count(t => t == ("A", "B"));
//もしくは
var count = strs.Zip(strs[1..]).Count(t => t == ("A", "B"));
```

- `Zip()`拡張メソッドは要素数を一致させる必要はなく、短い方に合わせてくれる仕様です。
- `.Where().Count()`というコードをよく見かけますが、[`Count()`拡張メソッド](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-8.0)には条件を満たす要素数を数えるオーバーロードが用意されています。
- `ValueTuple`は任意の要素数に対応できますが、`Zip()`拡張メソッドは２要素・３要素までしか用意されていません。

Comment: 丁寧な回答ありがとうございます！　こちらでも正しく動作しました。拡張メソッドについては勉強不足なところがあったので本当にありがたいです。返事が遅れて申し訳ないです

Answer (score 1):

バージョン指定がないので.Net8(C#12.0)に準拠します

```
//C#

using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Search words:[{0}]\nHit:{1}",
                          string.Join(" ",["A","B"]),
                          new[]{"A","B","F","D","A","B","A","G"}.CountSearch("A","B"));
    }
}

public static class Search
{
    public static int CountSearch<SearchType>(this SearchType[] sample,params SearchType[] target)
    {
        int count = default,range = target.Length;
        var element = static (SearchType[] array) => string.Join(" ",array);
        
        for(int final = range,start = default;final <= sample.Length;++final,++start)
            count = element(sample[start..final]) == element(target) ? ++count : count;
        
        return count;
    }
}
```

他の回答にもある通り、要素の逐次検証が堅実な手法と思われます

このコードではコレクションの範囲指定構文を用い、グループ化された要素同士の合致性を判定します

以下は結果です

```
Search words:[A B]
Hit:2
```

Answer (score 1):

C# 8.0以降では範囲構文を使えるので、`strs[..^1].Zip(strs[1..])`で少しだけ直感的なようなそうでもないような書き方ができます。

```
string[] strs = { "A", "B", "F", "D", "A", "B", "A", "G" };

var target = Tuple.Create("A", "B");
var count = strs[..^1].Zip(strs[1..]).Where(z => z.ToTuple().Equals(target)).Count();
//var count = strs[..^1].Zip(strs[1..]).Where(z => z.First == "A" && z.Second == "B").Count();  // FirstとSecondをそれぞれ比較する書き方でもOK

Console.WriteLine(count); // 2
```

**参考資料**

- [Range 構造体](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.range?view=net-7.0)
- [C# 8.0 Ranges](https://ufcpp.net/blog/2018/12/cs8ranges/)

Answer (score 0):

> ある配列から複数の要素が連続して含まれる数

[View on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EaAKPT)

```csharp
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] arr = ["A", "B", "F", "D", "A", "B", "A", "G"];
        string str = String.Join(null, arr);
        int count = Regex.Matches(str, "AB").Count;
        Console.WriteLine(count);
    }
}
```